# Azure CosmosDB MongoDB: WriteError - Request timed out

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

With my team we use the Azure Cosmosdb Mongodb service, and we are attempting to perform a `deleteMany()` operation. We get the following error:

```
$ mongo <connection-string> --eval 'db.trainingData.deleteMany({"data.intent" : "FIN INTENTION STANDARD"})'

. . .
. . .
. . .

WriteError({
        "index" : 0,
        "code" : 50,
        "errmsg" : "Request timed out.",
        "op" : {
                "q" : {
                        "data.intent" : "FIN INTENTION STANDARD"
                },
                "limit" : 0
        }
})
```

We have disabled throughput limiting on our Azure Cosmosdb instance but it doesn't solve the issue

[image]

Any idea as to why this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue came from throughput limiting **at collection level**, which I didn't know was a thing in Azure CosmosDB

By default throughput is limited to 400RU/S (Rate Unit per Second) on every collection

[image]

We switched it to `Autoscale` with a max limit of 10.000RU/s on the few collections involved, and it fixed the timeouts

[image]

Comment: try to use chunks. Using higher values on RU surely will helps but cost will rise, that's upon to you. Are you using Mongo API 4.2? because 3.6 costs higher